# Can I share my internet(lan) through Wifi(adhoc) connection via a laptop?

Tags: wireless, android, lan, adhoc

Is there a way I can share my lan internet connection through my wifi when I has an mesh connection from my android through the Open Garden Wifi Tethering App(A WiFi Tether AP Mesh Client)?

Link to: [Open Garden Wifi Tethering App](https://market.android.com/details?id=og.android.tether&feature=search_result)

Answer (score 2):

yes you can open network manger from the right side in the panel then click edit connection you will see all connection choose wireless and click add new set everything like ssd and password then go to ipv4 setting make the method "share to other computer"

Comment: Hmm the Open Garden Wifi Tethering App, make a mesh network with a defult ssd name(AndroidTether) I try then go to ipv4 setting and set the method to "share to other computer". But after this I can not even access my laptops Apache server via the Android's browser. ps I has updated the image a little!

Comment: well, i don't try it on "Open Garden Wifi Tethering App" but if you can't access the apache server maybe you have to reconfigure apache server to allow the android device or some ports ....

Comment: Ok. The apache server works! but when I set the method to "share to other computer" it stops functioning, and if I put it back it works again!

Answer (score 0):

Although software solutions exist, by far the simplest way is to buy a WiFi router which can be be had for less than $20 if you shop around. The only configuration required may be to clone the MAC address of your PC's Ethernet port in the router to allow the router to connect via your broadband connection. Many routers have an option to clone the MAC address for you. Just plug the modem into the WAN port of the router and your PC into one of the 4 available LAN ports. Then cold start modem, router and PC and all will work. Any WiFi device can connect to your router just as it would at Starbucks, McDonalds or wherever open WiFi connections are offered.

Comment: Thanks .. but the idea is to create a mesh network (see this https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2011/04/open-wireless-movement).
With ones pc/laptop as one of the internet-backends.
I would rather have it so that my laptop act as a WiFi mesh repeaters.
But as I understand it, I need to wifi card in my laptop for this to work.